# Image of Sylow Subgroup under Automorphism

Tags: sylow-theory

Let $G$ be finite with $G > 1$ and suppose $P \subseteq Aut(G)$ is a $p$-subgroup. Show that there exists some nontrivial Sylow $q$-subgroup $Q$ of $G$ (for some prime $q$) such that $\sigma(Q)=Q$, $\forall$ $\sigma$ $\in  P$.

I don't know how to attack the problem. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you see how to do this when $p$ divides $|G|$? (I don't quite see how to do the other case yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

The group $\;P\;$ acts on the set $\;Syl_q\;$of all the Sylow $\;q$-subgroups of $\;G\;$ ,  for each prime $\;q\;$ dividing $\;|G|\;$, by $\;\;\;\sigma\cdot Q:=\sigma(Q)\;,\;\;\forall\,Q\in S_q\;$ . By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, we get that

$$|\mathcal O(Q)|=[P:P_Q]\;,\;\;P_Q=\text{Stab}(Q):=\{\pi\in P\;;\;\;\pi(Q)=Q\;\}$$

If $\;p\mid |G|\;$ then $\;|Syl_p|=1\pmod p\;$ and we're done as it must be $\;|\mathcal O(Q)|=1\;$ for some $\;Q\in Syl_p\;\;\;$ (why?)

Otherwise (i.e., there exists a prime $\;q\neq p\;$ dividing the group's order), using $\;Syl_q^P:=\{ Q\in Syl_q\;:\;\;\sigma(Q)=Q\;,\;\;\forall\sigma\in P\}\;$ , [the fixed point theorem](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/the-p-group-fixed-point-theorem/) gives us

$$|Syl_q^P|=|Syl_q|\pmod p$$

Finish the proof now.

Comment: Nice, I knew there was some simple result I had forgotten and which would be useful for the case where $p$ does not divide the order of $G$. BTW, you might be interested in the chatroom for finite group theory http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19567/finite-group-theory

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks a lot, Tobias. I shall visit it later.

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks a lot. For the p||G|, O(Q) is divisible by p and |Syl_p| is sum of all orbits. So one of the orbits must be of order 1.
For the other case, q doesn't divide |Syl_q|=1 mod q. So the order of the set of fixed points has to be greater or equal to 1. Am I right?

Comment: @Zeus Yes to both cases.